# Python list comprehension to join list of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Given `lists = [['hello'], ['world', 'foo', 'bar']]`

How do I transform that into a single list of strings?

`combinedLists = ['hello', 'world', 'foo', 'bar']`

Comment: I know I can do it the long way by using nested loops, but I was wondering if there's a one-liner to do the same thing.

Comment: Another easy and fast way is:
>> lists = [['hello'], ['world', 'foo', 'bar']]
###################
>>combinedLists = lists[0] + lists[1]

Answer (score 139, accepted):

```
lists = [['hello'], ['world', 'foo', 'bar']]
combined = [item for sublist in lists for item in sublist]
```

Or:

```
import itertools

lists = [['hello'], ['world', 'foo', 'bar']]
combined = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(lists))
```

Comment: While the first choice looks nicer in my opinion. Using itertools is MUCH faster. This answer is great.

Comment: The first one looks nice. But its kind a hard for me to wrap my head around what variable goes where.

Comment: I was using old-school lazy looping over 90,000 entries in a DF.  It was taking forever.  I switch to this and it was instant! I knew it was magically faster, but that was just silly.

Comment: @Aidis for you or anyone else that also gets confused: the best way to remember is that from the `for`, the order of expressions is the same as a normal, nested for-loop.

Answer (score 9):

```
from itertools import chain

combined = [['hello'], ['world', 'foo', 'bar']]
single = [i for i in chain.from_iterable(combined)]
```